# user not able to login remotely to sssd configured linux host

Tags: sssd, pam-ldap

I have a RHEL host. I have configured sssd to connect to ldap server. The ldap user are not able to connect remotely to the host. However ever if i do su - username it work for me. but if the user tries to login via ssh it does not work.I get permission denied message. I am login to the server as root with ssh key to do the configuration and restart ofsssd. Below is the /etc/sssd/sssd.conf file.

```
[domain/example.com]
autofs_provider = ldap
id_provider = ldap
auth_provider = ldap
chpass_provider = ldap
ldap_schema = ad
ldap_referrals = False

ldap_uri = ldaps://ad.example.com
ldap_id_use_start_tls = False
ldap_tls_cacertdir = /etc/ssl/certs
ldap_tls_cacert = /etc/ssl/certs/myldap.pem

ad_access_filter = (&(memberOf=CN=webexample,OU=example groups,DC=example,DC=com)(unixHomeDirectory=*))


ldap_default_bind_dn = CN=webexample,OU=Generics,OU=example Users,DC=example,DC=com
ldap_default_authtok_type = password
ldap_default_authtok = mypassword 

ldap_pwd_policy = none

ldap_search_base = DC=example,DC=com
ldap_group_search_base = OU=example groups,DC=example,DC=com
ldap_user_search_base = OU=Employees,OU=example users,DC=example,DC=com
ldap_user_search_scope = sub

cache_credentials = true
account_cache_expiration = 7
entry_cache_timeout = 3600
enumerate = false
ldap_network_timeout = 3
ldap_account_expire_policy = ad
ldap_force_upper_case_realm = true
override_gid = 55999
ldap_id_mapping = true

ldap_user_object_class = person
ldap_user_name = cn
ldap_user_home_directory = unixHomeDirectory
ldap_user_principal = userPrincipalName
ldap_user_extra_attrs = mail, givenname, sn, displayname

ldap_group_object_class = group
ldap_group_name = cn
ldap_group_member = member
ldap_user_member_of = memberOf

subdomain_inherit = ignore_group_members, ldap_purge_cache_timeout
ignore_group_members = True
ldap_purge_cache_timeout = 0

[sssd]
config_file_version = 2
reconnection_retries = 3
sbus_timeout = 30
debug_timestamps = true
services = nss, pam 
domains = example.com

[nss]
filter_groups = root
filter_users = root
vetoed_shells = /bin/csh,/bin/zsh,/bin/ksh,/bin/tcsh,bin/sh
shell_fallback = /bin/bash
override_homedir = /home/%u

[pam]
offline_credentials_expiration = 3

[sudo]

[autofs]

[ssh]

[pac]

[secrets]
```

When i restart sssd i get the ssl error message.

```
Could not start TLS encryption. error:14090086:SSL routines:ssl3_get_server_certificate:certificate verify failed (unable to get local issuer certificate)
```